# Name for program that converts between two formats?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

This question is a little silly, but sometimes it's tough to figure out how to name things correctly.  The conversion will parse a config file into XML and vice versa.  I want to call the program MyCompany.Config2Xml, but the program also needs to be able to "Xml2Config".

Comment: Not a silly question. Names are powerful.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with COnfig2Xml.

Comment: I would not mention XML in the title, that is a technical aspect of the function that might be irrelevant to the user or that may change in the future.

Comment: Name it Config2Xml and add a -r switch, meaning reverse. Or maybe to make it clearer, name it ConfigToFromXml (and require options -2xml or -2config, one or the other). Alternately, if you want to do the work, the program could probably figure out what format the input is in, and merely reverse it. Because valid XML must start with "<" and end with ">," right (after skipping whitespace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General term seems like it would be format convertor, or transformatter (by analogy with transcoder).  In terms of the specific names you discuss, I think I'd go with ConfigConvertor.

Comment: @unknown: Your argument is persuasive.  Unfortunately this makes my answer almost a duplicate of danielmay's, except with more classicist spelling.

Comment: sorry, I moved my comment up, orphaning yours. What I said is to merge both suggestions into ConfigTransformatter.

Comment: Or, paraphasing the exact words of the question, ConfigFormatConverter

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Well, there's no need to insult the poor thing; it's just doing its job.

Comment: I like ConfigFormatConverter!

Answer (score 2):

I propose: ConfigParser

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with SqlDataReader, TextReader, XmlReader etc I'd just call it ConfigReader and ConfigWriter.

Or, you could just go the serialization approach and then not have to worry about naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

CC for short: 
ConfigConverter ?

Comment: CC is (almost) universally recognized as a C-compiler. CC would be a very bad name.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than ConfigParser as proposed by jeffamaphone (+1 for nice username), make it a verb:

```
parse-config
```

This makes it read nicely in scripts:

```
if ! parse-config < config-file > config.xml; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps a lot to think about the verbs (methods) you intend to use with the class and the role the class plays in the application.

In other words if you envision the operation to be {class}.**Get**() or {class}.**Load**() then ***ConfigParser*** might be a good choice.

If on the other hand you have a corresponding  {Class}.**Set**() or {class}.**Save**() operation then something like ***ConfigManager*** would be a better choice, particularly if the class will be used to isolate the application from the persistence of its configuration.

If the role of the class is nothing more than part of a standalone application or a step in a longer running process then I would would lean more towards class and method pairs that are more like **Convert.ToXml()** **Convert.ToConfig()** or **Translate.FromXml()** **Translate.FromConfig()**.

Answer (score 0):

DaTransmogrifier

UberConvertPlus

Xml2Config2Xml

ConfiguratorX

Answer (score 0):

'XConTrans'

or simply 'Via'

Answer (score 0):

ConfXmlSwitcher :P